# Prove such a function is constant

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x) = f(x^2)$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $0$, prove $f$ is constant. And the case $f$ is not contiunous at $0.$

I think it would be constant $f(0)$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the somewhat confusing wording of your question, it sounds like you want us to consider two cases.

**$f$ assumed continuous at $0$** For $x\in(-1,\,1)$, $f\left(x^{2^n}\right)$ is a constant sequence on $n\ge0$, so has limit $f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2^n}\right)=f(0)$ by the continuity of $f$ at $0$.

**$f$ not assumed continuous at $0$** For $x\in(-1,\,0)$, $f(x)=f(x^2)=f(|x|)$, so $f$ is even. On $(0,\,1)$ define the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ viz. $\ln 2|\ln\frac{x}{y}$, then choose arbitrary values of $f$ for each equivalence class, plus an arbitrary value at $0$. In general, $f$ will not be constant. For a simple counterexample, take $f$ to be constant except at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x|<1$ then $f(x)=f(x^{2^n}), \forall x \in (-1,1)$

But $y_n=x^{2^n} \to 0$ thus $f(x)=f(y_n) \to f(0)$ by continuity.

So $f(x)=f(0)$ on $(-1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in (0,1)=f(x)=f(x^{2^n})$ since $f(x^{2^{n+1}})=f((x^{2^n})^2)$ and $lim x^{2^n}=0$, since $f$ is continuous, $lim_nf(x^{2^n})=f(0)$